# Comparing two 2d tensors in PyTorch

Tags: python, for-loop, indexing, pytorch

I am quite new to PyTorch. I will like to know how to compare two tensors at the same index location in their respective tensors and output the maximum. For example, given a 4x4  tensors A and B as below:

```
A =tensor([[0.2846, 0.9896, 0.0401, 0.7612],
        [0.1508, 0.1701, 0.3395, 0.4106],
        [0.1685, 0.3624, 0.0622, 0.2306],
        [0.0880, 0.0559, 0.0294, 0.4382]])

B= tensor([[0.4853, 0.2833, 0.8011, 0.0570],
        [0.2024, 0.8363, 0.0883, 0.8944],
        [0.2973, 0.1669, 0.4703, 0.3508],
        [0.1581, 0.6574, 0.8502, 0.4210]])
```

I want to be able to compare A[0,0] with B[0,0], A[1,1] with B[1,1]...A[n,n] with B[n,n] and then output the max between the two.

What I have done: I have used nested loops like this :

```
 for i in range(A.size()[0]):
   for j in range(A.size()[1]): 
     for m in range(B.size()[0]):
       for n in range(B.size()[1]): 
         if A[i,j] > B[m,n]:
           max_nos = A[i,j]
           print(max_nos)
         else:
           max_nos = B[m,n]
           print(max_nos)
```

I got the result below which is not the result I want(dim 64,1):

```
   tensor(0.4853)
   tensor(0.2846)
   tensor(0.8011)
   tensor(0.2846)
   ...
   ...
   ...
```

From the tensor A and B above, my expected result should be (dim 16,1):

```
tensor(0.4853)
tensor(0.9896)
tensor(0.8011)
...
...
```

Thank you

Comment: `torch.max(A,B).view(-1, 1)` ?

Comment: Thank you! If you can add it as answer instead of comment so I can accept the answer. I really appreciate it